# Manipulate for loop to run code with specific variables only

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a for loop which I'd like to manipulate to take specific values for the variables.

```
  for ($ip=2; $ip <=100; $ip++) { 

        }
```

I want something along the lines of

```
  for ($ip=2; $ip=4; $ip=5; $ip=6; $ip=9;) { 

        }
```

Please note that some numbers are skipped so I just wanted to target specific numbers. I don't think we'll still need the for loop because this is like telling the code to use specific values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with the specific values and use a `foreach()` loop...

```
$ipList = [2, 4, 5, 6, 9];
foreach ( $ipList as $ip )   {

}
```